# How to insert text within an html attribute

Tags: python, html

I'm very new to working with HTML and have this little piece of code:

```
{% for x in query %}
            {% set outer_loop = loop %}
                 <div class="panel panel-info">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">{{ x.nickname }}</h3>
<br/>
                     <div class="progress">
                     <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-default"   
                        role="progressbar" aria-valuenow={{ 
                        x.readings[-1].level }} aria-valuemin="0" 
                        aria-valuemax="100" style="min-width: 2em; width: 2%;">
                     {{ x.readings[-1].level }}%
                     </div>
                     </div>
```

I want to be able to put this `{{ x.readings[-1].level }}`  value where the 2% is here:

```
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-default" role="progressbar"  aria-  
    valuenow={{ x.readings[-1].level }} aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"  
    style="min-width: 2em; width: 2%;">
```

Sorry, this is probably a very silly question, but I would appreciate any help I could get :)

Comment: What web framework are you working with? This kind of looks like Django, but I'm confused as this seems to be a question more particular to Javascript (or AJAX, specifically), and we know nothing about your pythonic views to help you from that end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Assuming you're using Django) With the built in template tags, anything marked with {{ }} is replaced with what's inside no matter where it is.

```
style="min-width: 2em; width: {{ x.readings[-1].level }};"
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you :) as a side note, I tried this but was missing a % sign on the end, so it should read:
style="min-width: 2em; width: {{ x.readings[-1].level }}%;"